# How to run multiple commands from Node JS using execSync in the one and same shell?

Tags: node.js, shell

I'm trying to figure out how to write sort of an install script in Node (yes, complete nightmare). I'm basically trying to figure out how I would go about; fetching git repo, cd into that repo, run various build commands and what have you.

But reading the node docs once again leaves me in the dark, as 'documentation' is basically a description of what methods are available ... and now YOU go figure out how it actually works in the real world – (EXAMPLES PLEASE! – apologies for letting the frustration shine through here).

I'm trying to run the two most basic commands I could think of:

`cd dir_name` and `pwd`

In an attempt to cd into a directory and print the working directory to actually see if I'm getting into the dir.

I got this part to work (yes, googling, guessing etc.):

```
const path = require('path');
const cp = require('child_process');

cp.execSync('git clone git@bitbucket.org<left blank>.git', {
    stdio: [0, 1, 2],
    cwd: path.resolve(__dirname, ''),
})
```

Now, I'm trying to enter this dir and execute further commands:

```
const cm1 = cp.spawnSync('cd dir_name', );
console.log( `cm1 stderr: ${ cm1.stderr }` );
console.log( `cm1 stdout: ${ cm1.stdout }` );

const cm2 = cp.spawnSync('pwd', );
console.log( `cm2 stderr: ${ cm2.stderr }` );
console.log( `cm2 stdout: ${ cm2.stdout }` );
```

I would expect to see this in the console:

```
cm2 stdout: path/to/dir_name
```

But this will obviously – for reasons that are unclear to me – not work.

As I understand it (from guessterpetating the google results I get) I'm actually starting up two different shells(!?) – oh, what a surprice.

Could someone shed some simple light on how to go about running a series of commands (commands that I would otherwise manually type into the Terminal and execute one by one) from a node script file (please, ignore the prerequisite scans needed for node being installed etc. let's not complicate things further)?

I had hoped it would be easier to run simple commands from node.

Comment: Same way you run multiple instructions on one line in any regular terminal: use `&&` to separate your commands. e.g. ``execSync(`git clone whatever && cd whatever && npm install`)``.

Comment: Not working, tried that. That's why I ended up on stackoverflow. Things rarely go as  you expect.

Comment: "Not working" doesn't mean anything: please show "proof" that things don't work by putting a [mcve] in your post, because the exec example I just gave you works perfectly fine (and is trivially shown to work using just the Node REPL). If your _specific_ set of commands don't work, show what you tried, so others can confirm that exact code doesn't work. But then also make sure they're not "toy" commands like `pwd`, because that's not the command(s) you _actually_ want, you just used that for testing.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm actually starting up two different shells(!?)

Yes thats why pwd is not same.

To get `cm2 stdout: path/to/dir_name` as output you need to run that command in same shell like this

```js
const cm1 = cp.spawnSync('cd dir_name && pwd'); // notice `&& pwd`
console.log( `cm1 stderr: ${ cm1.stderr }` );
console.log( `cm1 stdout: ${ cm1.stdout }` );
```

so what happens is node creates child process of shell (`/bin/sh`) with args as you have passed. its similar to running this command

```bash
$ /bin/sh -c "cd dir_name && pwd"
```

but you were doing this

```bash
$ /bin/sh -c "cd dir_name"
$ /bin/sh -c "pwd"
```

Hope you understand whats happening and where you got it wrong.

Here is improvised code

```js
//@ts-check

const util = require('util')
const cp = require('child_process')
const path = require('path')
const exec = util.promisify(cp.exec)

async function main() {
  const testcd = await exec(`cd dir_name && pwd && ls`) 
  process.stdout.write(testcd.stdout)
  process.stderr.write(testcd.stderr)

  console.log('cwd of parent process (nodejs)', process.cwd())
  const clonedir = path.join(process.cwd(), 'junk', 'cloned-repo')
  const gitclone = await exec(`git clone git@bitbucket.org.git ${clonedir}`) 
  // above is same as  /bin/sh -c "git clone git@bitbucket.org.git ./junk/cloned-repo"
  process.stdout.write(gitclone.stdout)
  process.stderr.write(gitclone.stderr)

}

main().catch(console.error)
```

if you are writing some complicated build steps, I would recommend using [gulp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp) or [make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html)